# mysql: Anagram query to pull every possible word with any letters

Tags: mysql, anagram

I am in the middle of building my anagram query which is almost working great. Here is my sql

The letters I am using are "settin?"

The difference is the wildcard which I will allow the user to add a "?" into the field.

```
SELECT `word`, 0+ABS(`e`-1)+ABS(`i`-1)+ABS(`n`-1)+ABS(`s`-1)+ABS(`t`-2) AS difference
FROM `TWL06`
WHERE LENGTH(`word`) <= 7
HAVING difference <= 1
```

My Table Structure is as

```
word | a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h | i | j | k | l | m | n | o | p | q | r | s | t | u | v | w | x | y | z |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
THIS | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
```

The problem with the query is that it will only pull words that contain all the letters with a difference of 0 or 1. It will not pull words that may be smaller in length that could contain some of the letters or shorter words like 2 3 4 5 6 letters long.

I thought WHERE LENGTH(`word`) <= 7 would take care of the length, but that seems to not work.

For Instance: SIT, TENTS, TEST

or even words with a difference of 1 wildcard like

TESTY (Y is the wildcard)

Any ideas?

Comment: this isn't going to work. to handle the shorter words, you'd need to produce an addition chain like you have above, for EVERY permutation of the letter possibilities, for every potential length of anagram you want. the sql will VERY quickly balloon into an outright hideous mess. As well, unless I'm missing something about your table structure, you're not subtracting letters. "``e``-1" is subtracting one from a field named "e".

Comment: forgot to mention my table structure so I added it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a fix for it

```
SELECT
    `word`,
    0+IF(`a` > 0, `a` - 0, 0)
    +IF(`b` > 0, `b` - 0, 0)
    +IF(`c` > 0, `c` - 0, 0)
    +IF(`d` > 0, `d` - 0, 0)
    +IF(`e` > 1, `e` - 1, 0)
    +IF(`f` > 0, `f` - 0, 0)
    +IF(`g` > 0, `g` - 0, 0)
    +IF(`h` > 0, `h` - 0, 0)
    +IF(`i` > 1, `i` - 1, 0)
    +IF(`j` > 0, `j` - 0, 0)
    +IF(`k` > 0, `k` - 0, 0)
    +IF(`l` > 0, `l` - 0, 0)
    +IF(`m` > 0, `m` - 0, 0)
    +IF(`n` > 1, `n` - 1, 0)
    +IF(`o` > 0, `o` - 0, 0)
    +IF(`p` > 0, `p` - 0, 0)
    +IF(`q` > 0, `q` - 0, 0)
    +IF(`r` > 0, `r` - 0, 0)
    +IF(`s` > 1, `s` - 1, 0)
    +IF(`t` > 2, `t` - 2, 0)
    +IF(`u` > 0, `u` - 0, 0)
    +IF(`v` > 0, `v` - 0, 0)
    +IF(`w` > 0, `w` - 0, 0)
    +IF(`x` > 0, `x` - 0, 0)
    +IF(`y` > 0, `y` - 0, 0)
    +IF(`z` > 0, `z` - 0, 0) AS difference
FROM `TWL06`
WHERE LENGTH(`word`) <= 8
HAVING difference <= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

populated a table: `anagram (word, sorted_word)` where `word` contains "setting", "apple", etc. and `sorted_word` contains "eginstt", "aelpp", etc.

to find anagrams of setting, first get the sorted word: `select sorted_word from anagram where word = "setting"` then use that sorted word to get all anagrams: `select word from anagram where sorted_word = "eginstt"`

you can do it in a single query too.

Comment: forgot to mention my table structure so I added it