# Anagram solver(best practice)

Tags: mysql

Kinda new to mysql and am creating a game where my algorithm pick one word from a table with the English dictionary in it and the user is supposed to guess as many valid English words that can be derived from that word. However I don't want to search the database every time the user submits an answer to check for its validity. So I wanted a way to query my dictionary table and retrieve every word that can be formed from the letters of the root word so that I store those words in the app and anytime the user submits a word I check from that list to reduce data usage.

```
E.g root word:contaminate
submissions: eat is valid so will show in the generated list
         mind is invalid because 'd' is not in root word so won't show in query results.
```

If there is a way to do this with just a query or will have to add php to make it work I'll be glad to have any help at all. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new column on the dictionary table, then run a algorithm to populate it with the number of matches.

All these "%like%" queries during runtime will have a extremely low performance, but if you pre calculate this field, things will be almost immediate.

I don't see how to do this with a single query, you will need to split the word  to smaller ones then query against the dictionary table.

Ex:

```
like '%contaminate%' 
like '%contaminat%'
like '%contamina%'
like '%contamin%'
...
like '%ontaminate%'
like '%ntaminate%'
like '%taminate%'
...
like '%ont%'
like '%ami%'
like '%nat%'
...
```

Edit: (Sorry, I had misunderstood your question)

See: [mysql: Anagram query to pull every possible word with any letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17285723/mysql-anagram-query-to-pull-every-possible-word-with-any-letters)

Comment: Edited my post with the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17285723/mysql-anagram-query-to-pull-every-possible-word-with-any-letters

Answer (score 0):

If you populate a further column in your table with the letters of each word ordered alphabetically, e.g.:

```
silent eilnst
listen eilnst
```

This could be populated once when building up your table.

You can then query your table once to get all the words which have the exact same set of letters as in your original choice.